# Trouble when trying to use Nhibernate.Linq

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have been trying to implement Nhibernate.Linq 1.0.0.4000 together with Nhibernate 2.1.2.4000. After what I've read that should be a straightforward process - just adding a reference to Nhibernate.Linq and then start querying with Session.Linq<>..

So.. In my repository I added a very simple query:

```
  var query = (from l in _session.Linq<User>()  select l);
  return query.ToList();
```

However I run into an error I just can't understand. The error message is:

> {"Entry point was not found.":""}
>
> at
>   NHibernate.ISession.get_SessionFactory()
>   at
>   NHibernate.Linq.NHibernateQueryProvider.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   expression)    at
>   NHibernate.Linq.NHibernateQueryProvider.Execute(Expression
>   expression)    at
>   NHibernate.Linq.Query`1.GetEnumerator()
>   at
>   System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()

Initially I thought It could be related to me configuring and mapping with Fluentnhibernate, but after reverting to vanilla config and mapping, I still have the same problem.

Should I switch the above linq-query to the ICriteria equivalent, it works like a charm.

Has this happened to anyone else? Do you have a solution?

TIA
//Marcus

Comment: You are using Linq to Hibernate, not implementing it. or i am wrong?

Comment: That is correct (or trying to use one might say). I'll change the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using the wrong build of NHibernate.Linq.

[This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.2GA/NHibernate.Linq-2.1.2-GA-Bin.zip/download) is the one you should download.

Comment: Oh - or maybe I should say 'Doh' =) Thanks - it worked like a charm!